# SPI: Receiving bytes from slave

Tags: avr, spi, rfid, atmega328p

For a couple of days I have been learning about SPI and decided to give it a go with 2 small devices.

- DEVICE 1: Atmega328p (MASTER)
- DEVICE 2: [MFRC522](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf) (SLAVE)

As far as I understand:

- master sets SS pin low
- master moves data to SPDR
- as soon as data gets in to SPDR clock starts transmitting and data shift out
- at the same time SLAVE shift data out too
- so by the end of 8 clock pulses SLAVE received 1 byte and master received 1 byte too
- SS pin goes high again

## Scenario #1

I am sending the address byte to MFRC522 from Atmega328p, and expecting a reply. According to the documentation, the first response from SLAVE is "X" I take it as 0x00.

On the next byte sent to the SLAVE, I receive the response from the first byte I sent, and so on until the end.

Since it has some kind of offset would I need to send 0x00 to the slave to read that last byte of information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table 6 on p.11 of the datasheet is pretty explicit:

Yes, to receive the Nth data byte, you need to transmit 00 in the (N+1)th transfer.

Comment: 00 is 0b00000000 ? that what confused me:) thanks man

Comment: Most often it doesn't actually matter what the master sends while the slave is replying with data words; all that is actually needed are the clock cycles.